# How to make sure the 'fit_generator' in Keras scan the data set for multiple times?

Tags: memory, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to construct one LSTM model for classification. And I used the fit_generator to fit the memory. The codes are:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(data_dim, return_sequences=True,
           input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))  # return the target value

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics= ['accuracy'])
encoder = load_model('encoder.h5')
model.fit_generator(generate_batches_from_file(path, batchSize, raw_targets, class_weights),
      steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
      epochs=scans * n_chunks_train )
```

And the generator code is like:

```
def generate_batches_from_file(path, batchSize, raw_targets, class_weights):
    while True:
        with open(path, 'r') as file_to_read:
            do_somthing()
            yield something
```

After processing 'batchSize' data, we will yield something.

My Question is: In my eyes, the 'generate_batches_from_file' generator will read the file to the end only once. At the end of the file, it will break the while loop. If I want to scan the file multiple times, what should I do? Could I set some parameters to achieve this?

Comment: It will read the file multiple times. You have written `with open()`, so when it reaches the end of the file, the program will close the file. Since you are in a `while` loop, you will come back to the line `with open()` , open the file and start reading from line 1 again. However, you are not shuffling your data at the beginning of each epoch.

Comment: Why do want scan the same data multiple times?.. 
Are you in need of more data or?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thank you. I have another question. Since I cannot load the whole data set into memory, then how could I do the shuffling? Is it that I do the shuffling based on each batch?